# Nirgam runtime error using SystemC in Mac OS X

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, clang, lldb, systemc

I am running the [nirgam](http://nirgam.ecs.soton.ac.uk/) 3.0, which is a open source SystemC based NoC simulator in my MacBook(Mac OS X 10.10). I successfully compile the nirgam source code, but when is try to run it, it throws the "segmentation fault" as showing:

```
╰─$ ./nirgam

        SystemC 2.3.1-Accellera --- May  3 2015 19:32:31
        Copyright (c) 1996-2014 by all Contributors,
        ALL RIGHTS RESERVED
[1]    5067 segmentation fault  ./nirgam

    (lldb) r
    Process 5076 launched: './nirgam' (x86_64)
```

I tried to using `lldb` to find out the error, and I got following hints:

```
        SystemC 2.3.1-Accellera --- May  3 2015 19:32:31
        Copyright (c) 1996-2014 by all Contributors,
        ALL RIGHTS RESERVED
Process 5076 stopped
* thread #1: tid = 0x7321, 0x00000001000c9d8d nirgam`sc_main(argc=1, argv=0x00000001004060f0) + 45 at main.cpp:62, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7fff5eb2dd18)
    frame #0: 0x00000001000c9d8d nirgam`sc_main(argc=1, argv=0x00000001004060f0) + 45 at main.cpp:62
   59
   60   int sc_main(int argc, char *argv[])
   61   {
-> 62       system("rm -rf *.txt");
   63       system("rm -rf jitter/GT/*");
   64       system("rm -rf jitter/BE/*");
   65       cout<<"---------------------------------------------------------------------------"<<endl;
(lldb) bt
* thread #1: tid = 0x7321, 0x00000001000c9d8d nirgam`sc_main(argc=1, argv=0x00000001004060f0) + 45 at main.cpp:62, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7fff5eb2dd18)
  * frame #0: 0x00000001000c9d8d nirgam`sc_main(argc=1, argv=0x00000001004060f0) + 45 at main.cpp:62
    frame #1: 0x0000000100238778 libsystemc-2.3.1.dylib`sc_elab_and_sim + 184
    frame #2: 0x00007fff879a65c9 libdyld.dylib`start + 1
    frame #3: 0x00007fff879a65c9 libdyld.dylib`start + 1
```

Following fact can be a hint:

1. I can compile and run other SystemC based including Noxim and other code I have writed in my system enviroment.
2. The lldb information show that there is an error occured when going to `sc_main`, which is a main function in SystemC based modeling.

My question is:

1. What does `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` mean when calling the `sc_main` function?
2. Is there any method I can use to get closer to the source of this bug ?

Comment: Check out the man page for system().  It discusses circumstances where system() will not work properly, and suggests using exec() in those cases.

Comment: Also, do you have any global variables, C++ objects in particular, that could be executing code before sc_main()?  If so, there is a remote chance code it is clobbering the string literals passed to system(), before system() gets a crack at them.  It's highly unlikely, but happened before.